# Twitter Bootstrap: Can't get navbar centered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I searched around and used all the solutions that worked for others - but unfortunately not for me.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
           <div class="container">
                 <ul class="nav">
                      <li class="active"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                 </ul>
           </div><!-- container -->
      </div><!-- navbar-inner -->
 </div><!--  navbar navbar-fixed-top -->
```

CSS things i've added

```
.navbar .nav,
.navbar .nav > li {
  float:none;
  display:inline-block;
  *display:inline; /* ie7 fix */
  *zoom:1; /* hasLayout ie7 trigger */
  vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar-inner {
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this -

```
.navbar {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: for margin: 0 auto;  to work you need to give .navbar a set width

Comment: where do i have to set the width then?

Comment: I've added it to my answer. You set it to the containing div, in this case .navbar